# product name description company using cart sesssion magento

Tags: magento, mage

I am trying to get the product details in onepage.php but i am failed. I have tried many codes but i am not getting it. Do i need to get it using the sessions ? anybody know the code how do i will get the product details inside the onepage.php page ?

ok first when i click buy a product it redirect to checkout/cart/ which means cart.phtml and cart.php well in this page i have the product name price qauntity grand total. Ok after i click the Procced to checkout then it redirect to checkout/onepage/ ... onepage.php and onepage.phtml

ok now i have set a email in the onepage.php that whenever the user click in the Procced to checkout button from the cart page when the onepage.php load it will send email.

Well now inside the email i would like to add the product details like product name quantity company name. In here i have completed all steps but can't get the product details. The product will be the product the user select to procced checkout.

```
here is my simple email template:
    $to = "$email";
    $from = "test@test.com";
    $subject = "email test";
    //begin of HTML message
    $message = <<<EOF
<html>
  <body bgcolor="#DCEEFC">
    <center>
        <b>email test</b> <br>
        <h1><font color="red">Your Coupon Code:</font>$letters$random_chars<br></h1>

<h1>Product Name : $productname</h1>
<h1>Company Name : $comname</h1>
    </center>

  </body>
</html>
EOF;
$headers  = "From: $from\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";


mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

well so here i have send the email its working fine just need to include the product name and company name but i am not getting how i will get it ?

Answer (score 0):

The product that available in checkout doesn't contain all of the attributes. You should define what attributes will be available on checkout/cart section from `config.xml`

```
<sales>
  <quote>
    <item>
      <product_attributes>
        <product_attribute_1/>
        <product_attribute_2/>
      </product_attributes>
    </item>
  <quote>
<sales>
```

*The trick belongs to Tim Milhouse from Brim LLC*

**EDIT :**
Include variables in transactional emails...
Lets say you had created a product attribute which is the name `product_origin`

- Create transactional email templates and modify as follows :

```
<html>
   <h1>Dear {{htmlescape var=$order.getCustomerName()}}</h1>
   <p>Thank you choosing {{var store.getFrontendName()}}</p>
   <h2>Here is the order details</h2>
   {{block type='core/template' area='frontend' template='/emails/product_info.phtml' order=$order}}
</html>
```

- Create product template `product_info.phtml`

```
# File path : /app/design/frontend/[YOUR_NAMESPACE]/[YOUR_THEME]/template/emails/product_info.phtml
 <?php $_order = $this->getOrder(); ?>
 <table>
   <tr>
     <td>Product Name</td>
     <td>Price</td>
     <td>Product Origin (Attribute)</td>
   </tr>
   <?php foreach($_order->getAllItems() as $_item): ?>
   <tr>
     <td><?php echo $_item->getName() ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $_order->formatPrice($_item->getPrice()) ?></td>
     <td>
        <?php
           $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
           $_product ->load($_item->getProductId());
           echo $_product->getProductOrigin(); // product attribute, if attribute name productorigin, therefore should be getProductorigin
        ?>
     </td>
   </tr>
   <?php endforeach ?>
 </table>
```

Comment: i just need to get the product name company name of the particular product that i am going to buy on the onpage.php . Because i am sending a email from onepage.php page and i have to include the name of the product. Can you please describe more clearly

Comment: I didn't understand correctly. If you get only product details that available in cart you can do. Because, product name, quantity etc. already available.

Comment: well not getting done . I guess it was my mistake i couldn't make you understand. Well let me give you full details :
    $message =
<html><b>Email<br><br>Product Name : $pro</h1>             
</body>
</html>
EOF;$headers  = "From: $from\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

  
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);                                                                     Here i want to get the product name in the onepage.php and this is my email thing which i have included in the onepage.php file i have no problem sending email but can't get the product name

Comment: <span class=" product-description" style="">
        <?php if ($this->hasProductUrl()):?>
            <?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getProductName()) ?>
        <?php else: ?>
            <?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getProductName()) ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        </span></div>                 this is the class which shows the name of the product but when i try it in onepage.phtml or onepage.php nothing appear

Comment: sorry for my bad english . i edited my question with all details. Please check and if you can help me out thanks